# Forms not working with array fields

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, forms, array, http-error-500

Don't know something has gone wrong. Suddenly on my magento (1.9) site forms which have array fields are not working.

for example :-

```
<input type="text" name="inputfield['first']" id="inputfieldfirst" value="" />
```

If I would take it as `name="inputfield"`, it will work.

And secondly (for debugging this issue) , I have created one file on root folder of magento directory which is having two forms 1] one is submitting data on root response file. 2] second is submitting data in app folder's custom module's controller. In these cases , first case is working but second is not working as it is submitting data into magento's controller.

Same code is working on another server.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: Try `name="inputfield[]"`